# How to write a docker-compose for an application that runs in a cluster

Tags: docker-compose, cluster-computing, docker-swarm

I'm setting up a monitoring stack in a docker swarm, and need to configure both prometheus alertmanager and hashicorp consul.

Both of these tools need to know either the hostnames or IP addresses of the other cluster members on startup. These settings can be passed via the environment.

Is there a way of doing this in a docker-compose file that I can pass to docker stack deploy?

**What I have checked so far**
I've looked at other people's solutions, and most of them appear to rely on using cloud platform templating while creating the swarm to generate the necessary configuration, or are forcing the nodes to have a known static IP.

I'd like a solution that can declaratively describe the service configuration. Host affinity on the swarm is acceptable, I'm intending to run both services on 1 container per swarm manager host in a 3-swarm-manager configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I've figured out a method that results in a clear and simple compose file, but with the downside that you need to define a service definition per clustered service instance you want to run.

```
services:
  alertmanager_1: # First cluster instance
    image: prom/alertmanager:latest
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml'
      - '--storage.path=/alertmanager'
      - '--cluster.peer=tasks.alertmanager_2:9094'  # links to second cluster instance via overlay DNS
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == swarm-manager000000
    networks:
      prometheus_stack:
        aliases:
          - alertmanager
    ports:
        - '19093:9093'
    volumes:
      - alertmanager-data:/alertmanager
      - alertmanager-config:/etc/alertmanager
  alertmanager_2: # Second cluster instance
    image: prom/alertmanager:latest
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/alertmanager/alertmanager.yml'
      - '--storage.path=/alertmanager'
      - '--cluster.peer=tasks.alertmanager_1:9094' # refers to the first

...

networks:
  prometheus_stack:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

The numbered service instances allow you to provide the correct peer configuration command lines without prior knowledge of the hostnames, and the overlay network alias allows you to refer to the cluster as a whole in other configuration that needs that DNS config.
Extending this to a larger cluster would involve adding more service definitions and adding a `--cluster.peer` entry for each extra instance.
I've fully described the process [here](https://albersdevelopment.net/2019/05/06/prometheus-alertmanager-cluster-in-docker-swarm/)

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a custom overlay network (you should) for your service, you can retrieve the ip-addresses of all the containers in the 'myservice' service by using:

`dig tasks.myservice +short`

Comment: I was aware of this feature, only what it couldn't do was give me single IP's per server to map to the multiple --cluster.peer command line flags the alertmanager service definition command line. Thankfully i've worked out a method that works, even though it forces me to use a service definition per cluster member. Solution [here](https://albersdevelopment.net/2019/05/06/prometheus-alertmanager-cluster-in-docker-swarm/)